# Isometric operators close to the identity

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

In a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ there are unitary operators in the neighborhood of the identity. For instance, via the Stone's theorem we can construct a strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group $U(t)$ such that $U(0)=\mathbb{I}$. My question is whether is this also true for isometric operators which are not unitary. Namely, can we construct a strongly continuous one-parameter family of isometric operators (but not unitary) $T(t)$ such that $T(0)=\mathbb{I}$?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, take $L^2(\mathbb R_+)$ and the isometries $I_t$ given by $I_t(f)(s) = f(s - t) \mathbb{1}_{[t, \infty)}$

Comment: I ment $L^2$, not $L^1$

Comment: Thank you! I had the apparently wrong feeling that in the neighborhood of the identity there are only invertible operators. Perhaps this is just true in finite dimension.

Comment: That is true in the norm topology, not in the strong one.

Comment: I see. Is the proof along this line?: $\|(\mathbb{I}-I_t) \|\geq\|(\mathbb{I}-I_t) f \|$, then for any finite $t$ we can take $f$ to be outside the image of $I_t$ and the norm is lower bounded by a positive number.